# centralized deterministic Spanner construction with low degree and low stretch

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, dc.distributed-comp, computational-geometry, network-modeling

Does there exist a centralized deterministic spanner construction with low degree and low stretch both independent of the graph diameter (no log D factor), but can be dependent on the number of nodes. There exists distributed spanner construction algorithms that satisfy this property, so I believe there should exist a simpler centralized counterpart.